# CSAwesome chapter 6.3

Tags: java, computer-science

Can Anyone help me out with the problem I encountered here? I did everything exactly the same with the example they provided to make an enhanced for loop. What should I do to solve this?

this is my code

```
public class EvenLoop {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int[]values={6,2,1,7,12,5};
        //Rewriter this loop as a for each loop and run 
        for (int v: values){
            if (values [v] % 2 == 0)
                System.out.println(values[v]+"  is even!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and can you then please add both the code and the full error to the question as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 4):

**Is this what you want**

```
public class EvenLoop {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int[]values={6,2,1,7,12,5};
        CheckNum(values);
        //Rewriter this loop as a for each loop and run
    }
    public static void CheckNum(int[]a){
        for(int j = 0 ; j <  a.length; j++){
            int key = a[j];
            if (key % 2 == 0)
                System.out.println(key +"  is even!");
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can only delete the (values) in the condition clause and print at the end of the code and Handling (v)

from

```
for (int v: values){
    if (values [v] % 2 == 0)
        System.out.println(values[v]+"  is even!");
}
```

to

```
for (int v: values){
            if (v % 2 == 0) 
                System.out.println(v+"  is even!");
        }
```

.

```
public class EvenLoop {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int[]values={6,2,1,7,12,5};
        //Rewriter this loop as a for each loop and run 
        for (int v: values){
            if (v % 2 == 0) 
                System.out.println(v+"  is even!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going outside the bounds of the array. In your loop, you use `for ( int n : values)`, which does not use indexes,  and instead uses the actual values in the array. The first value in your array is `6`. When you then do `values[n]` in your statements, you are doing `values[6]`. Since your array is only 6 elements long, it has valid indices from `0` to `5`, so `values[6]` is out of bounds, and you get the error.

To fix it, simply change your statements to `n` instead of `values[n]`